# gcm_defaultsenderid Error: Duplicate

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Buena tarde!! estoy trabajando con un proyecto la cual me da el sigueinte error, ya localice ambos archivos y no te que el nombre del recurso gcm_defaultsenderid esta en ambos, comente el de Strings pero no logre corregir el error.
Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas Gracias!!

Nota: hago uso de google-services.json, el error ocurrio despues de integrar fire base al proyecto.

```
 Error:Error: Duplicate resources
 Error:com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: [string/gcm_defaultSenderId] /Users/omnius/Desktop/Ominoz src 4 18.55.05/Customer/src/main/res/values/strings.xml  [string/gcm_defaultSenderId] /Users/omnius/Desktop/Ominoz src 4 18.55.05/Customer/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
 Error:[string/gcm_defaultSenderId] /Users/omnius/Desktop/Ominoz src 4 18.55.05/Customer/src/main/res/values/strings.xml    [string/gcm_defaultSenderId] /Users/omnius/Desktop/Ominoz src 4 18.55.05/Customer/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

Este es mi archivo de strings

Please enter email id
    Please enter password
    Password should be at least 6 charater long

```
 <string name="text_enter_valid_email">Please enter valid email id</string>
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId">149073305394</string>
    <string name="text_enter_name">Please enter first name</string>
    <string name="text_enter_lname">Please enter last name</string>
```

Este es el values.xml de google-services

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">182999935713-fmun1ag2bepcj7fn7felns7ef3l45u37.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">https://taximx-ab2a1.firebaseio.com</string>
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">149073305394</string>
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">AIzaSyAUlg7iMhBHAPis6AEzQy91YSnD51FtE9k</string>
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:149073305394:android:46ea606241308d01</string>
    <string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key" translatable="false">AIzaSyAUlg7iMhBHAPis6AEzQy91YSnD51FtE9k</string>
    <string name="google_storage_bucket" translatable="false">taximx-ab2a1.appspot.com</string>
    <string name="project_id" translatable="false">taximx-ab2a1</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Debes de ser mas especifico al preguntar, por lo menos agregar el código del .json y/o capturas de los archivos "localizados", así es demasiado difícil ayudarte

Comment: Ya intentaste renombrar de tu archivo de strings  esta <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId"> linea?

Comment: Si ya lo hice y sigue el error, a lo mejor importe mal la librería, volver a hacerlo

Comment: @UlisesDíaz al mostrarse este error y abrir el archivo del problema, revisa en la barra principal de android studio que ubicación se muestra.